# Latvian characters into MySQL Database converting

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have some problem. I have some data in my DB in Latvian (i.e `Valentīna`) and I need to display this on my page.
Other data are saved in cp1257 encoding and looks like `AÎDA MACIJEVSKA` - and it displays as `Aīda Macijevska`

So what I have tried...

```
1 - ucwords(mb_strtolower(iconv("windows-1257", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", trim($row['pac_name'])), "UTF-8"));
2 - ucwords(mb_strtolower(iconv("windows-1257", "UTF-8", trim($row['pac_name'])), "UTF-8"));
3 - just show without any converting from DB `$row["pac_name"]`;
```

and all 3 points display same result - `Valent?na`

P.S Database has utf8_general_ci collation, also I gave header for utf-8 encoding - `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

So can anyone please help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are truly using cp1257 and not utf8, then you need

- `SET NAMES cp1257` (or some other way for the *client* to tell *mysqld* that the bytes are encoded using cp1257)
- `CHARACTER SET cp1257` on each column (or perhaps defaulting from table definition).

But it sounds like you should go with utf8, not cp1257...

As I see it, `Î` does not exist in `cp1257`.  Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1257 .  Hence, the code you mentioned is free to screw it up, by either using `ī` or `?`.

If you really need I-hat, go with `utf8`.  Note that the collation `utf8_latvian_ci` exists.  All the i's mentioned here do exist in utf8.

If you have further questions, please provide `SELECT HEX(col)...` for any text in question.  For example (with spaces added for clarity):

In utf8: AÎDA --> 41 **C38E** 44 41; Aīda --> 41 **C4AB** 64 61
In cp1257:  Aīda --> 41 **EE** 64 61

Comment: I updated my list of [utf8 Collation Variations](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#utf8_collation_variations_) to include utf8_latvian_ci and the various Latvian-specific characters.  I see, for example, that `Ģ` sorts after `G`, but `Ī` is considered equal to `I` according to utf8_latvian_ci.